# Cómo podria ignorar los acentos en una busqueda con filtro

Tags: javascript, tildes

Estoy implementando una búsqueda con filtro, y lo que quiero es que al buscar en el campo salga la lista con las palabras y sus tildes correspondientes pero en el buscador pueda ponerlas sin tildes.

Por ejemplo: Álava si pongo en el buscador alava, que me responda con Álava.

Lo único que he podido conseguir es quitarlas, pero eso no me serviría.
Gracias de antemano.

```javascript
ignorePosh(s){
   let accent_map = {'á':'a', 'é':'e', 'è':'e', 'í':'i','ó':'o','ú':'u','Á':'a', 'É':'e', 'è':'e', 'Í':'i','Ó':'o','Ú':'u'};
    if (!s) { return ''; }
    var ret = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
       ret += accent_map[s.charAt(i)] || s.charAt(i);
    }
    return ret;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría que vuelvas tu cadena de búsqueda en un slug, esto seria el formato que suelen tener las url: caracteres en minúsculas, guiones en lugar de espacios, sin acentos. Esto lo puedes lograr así:

```
// Función para convertir string en slug
String.prototype.slug=function (separator="-") {
    return this.toString().normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '').toLowerCase().trim().replace(/[^a-z0-9 ]/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, separator);
};
```

Y en base a tu ejemplo lo podrías utilizar así:

```
function ignorePosh(s) {
    if (!s) {
        return '';
    }
    return s.slug();
}
```